# Add a label to a DataGrid's TemplateField itemtemplate. But not the front end

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, templatefield

C#, .net

Original Code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <itemtemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lblDependency" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </itemtemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
 BoundField bf = new BoundField();
 bf.DataField = "b";
 grvList.Columns.Add(bf);
```

but instead of boundfield, using templatefield.

If you would like to know why am I doing something like this, it has to do with: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552531/c-changing-the-order-of-columns-when-binding-datatable-to-a-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa289501 Covers this I believe (scroll down to the bottom for a DataGrid complete example). Basically you cannot have it parse ASP tags directly, you have to create a custom class that implements them programmatically, then instantiate that class.