# Column values in Grid View not showing in order - C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am having some trouble with this code, I am passing rows from one Grid View to another, but the Grid View is not displaying the data in order.

```
    System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;

    public partial class PuntoVenta : Page
    {

     DataTable dtband = new DataTable();        

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

      if (!IsPostBack)
     {

            DataTable dtbind = new DataTable();
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Id");
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Qnt");
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Unit");
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Name");
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Rel");
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Price");
            dtbind.Columns.Add("Class");
            Session["ss"] = dtbind;
    }
    }

    protected void GridViewA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)       {

      dtband = (DataTable)Session["ss"];        

      DataRow dataRow;
      dataRow = dtband.NewRow();
      int i2 = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < dataRow.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
        dataRow[i] = GridViewA.SelectedRow.Cells[i2].Text;

        i2++;
          }
 dtband.Rows.Add(dataRow);

                GridViewB.DataSource = dtband;
                GridViewB.DataBind();
}
}
```

> When I run the code, The GridViewB is populated but its first Column is empty, furthermore, the values that should be displayed in the first column, are displayed in the second column.

Comment: Where is variable i of dataRow[i] declared and changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2552566/3583859 try this

Comment: Hi Lei, I have updated the code

Comment: Please spend a few minutes formatting your code properly. Also, you've posted your edit as a new answer. Please click the 'edit' button on your question to make changes to the post

Comment: @richardkb please mark Vijay Kumbhoje's post as a accepted answer.. it will be helpfull for you and others also

Answer (score 1):

You can set `DiplayIndex` property of `Gridview Column`,

```
//Here 1 is index of desired column
datagridview1.Columns["ColumnName"].DisplayIndex = 1;
```

Add below code in your application

```
    dtbind.Columns.Add("Id");
    dtbind.Columns["Id"].DisplayIndex = 0;
    dtbind.Columns.Add("Qnt");
    dtbind.Columns["Qnt"].DisplayIndex = 1;
    //Like onwards
```

For more info on DisplayIndex property refer [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi Vijay, When I add that to my come I get the following error:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Data.DataColumn' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayIndex' and no extension method 'DisplayIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If it help you please mark it as answer Thanks and be well :)

Comment: @DSLR yawarshich kar mhanav